# Funcionamiento de punteros en C

Tags: c, punteros

No me funciona mi puntero en una función, bien tengo esta función:

```
void csn(char *tag_uid){
    
    int error = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    nfc_device *device = NULL;
    FreefareTag *tags = NULL;

    nfc_connstring devices[8];
    size_t device_count;

    nfc_context *context;
    nfc_init(&context);
    if (context == NULL)
    errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to init libnfc (malloc)");

    device_count = nfc_list_devices(context, devices, 8);
    if (device_count <= 0)
    errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "No NFC device found.");

    for (size_t d = 0; d < device_count; d++) {
        device = nfc_open(context, devices[d]);
        if (!device) {
            warnx("nfc_open() failed.");
            error = EXIT_FAILURE;
            continue;
        }
   
        tags = freefare_get_tags(device);
        if (!tags) {
            nfc_close(device);
            errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error listing tags.");
        }

        for (int i = 0; (!error) && tags[i]; i++) {

            tag_uid = freefare_get_tag_uid(tags[i]);

        }
    freefare_free_tags(tags);
    nfc_close(device);
    }
    nfc_exit(context);
    exit(error);
}
```

Y esta es la parte de mi **main**:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char uid;
    csn(&uid);
    printf("===> CSN %s:\n", uid);
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que al yo declarar una variable en el main y pasarla por parametro a la función, esta variable ya salga de la función con el valor asignado..¿Saben si estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Si `freefare_get_tag_uid` retorna un `char*`, y quieres acceder a el en el `main`, tienes que tomar un `char**` en `csn`, asignar el valor asi: `*tag_uid = freefare_get_tag_uid(tags[i]);`, y cambiar la declaracion en `main` por `char *uid;`

Comment: @Pablochaches Es una pregunta bastante bien formulada (para lo que se suele ver). No es un error tipográfico. Es un problema real. ¿ Porqué no escribes una respuesta ? Los comentarios no son respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centrándonos en lo que preguntas, tu problema es muy simple:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    char uid;
    csn(&uid);
```

- Creas una variable `uid`.
- Pasas **una variable oculta** (que contiene la dirección de `uid`) a tu función `csn( )`.

Dentro de `csn( )`:

```
void csn( char *tag_uid ) {
   ...
    tag_uid = freefare_get_tag_uid( tags[i] );
```

- Recibes una variable de tipo `char *` (que, recordemos, es una variable *oculta* creada dentro de `main( )`.
- Le asignas un valor.

Con eso, lógicamente tu variable original `uid` se queda **exactamente como estaba**.

Si miramos la definición de `freefare_get_tag_uid( )`:

```
char *freefare_get_tag_uid( MifareTag tag );
```

Vemos que, efectivamente, los tipos coinciden. El compilador no te muestra ningún error ni *aviso* (bueno, a lo mejor algo relativo a asignación sin efecto o algo así) ... pero no funciona :-)

La solución pasa por hacer algunos cambios:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    char *uid;
    csn( &uid );
```

con lo cual tu variable *destino* se adecua al valor devuelto por la función a la que pretendes llarmar. Pero claro, entonces también hay que *retocar* un poco tu función `csn( )`:

```
void csn( char **tag_uid ) {
    ...
    *tag_uid = freefare_get_tag_uid( tags[i] );
    ...
```

Con eso debería bastar. Tu función ahora recibe un *puntero-a-puntero* que, al direccionarlo (`**`) devuelve un `char *` que coincide con lo que devuelve `freefare_get_tag_uid( )`.